# Full Calendar, how to render event id once a new event has been added

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

So I am using Fullcalendar for my calendar solution.

I display my events from the database using the below:

```
events: "/Job/GetJobCalendarEvents?jobId=" + jobId
```

The code that provides the events is as below:

```
        List<CalendarAppointment> apps = new List<CalendarAppointment>();
        foreach (var id in interviewDates)
        {
            apps.Add(new CalendarAppointment()
            {
                id = id.Id,
                title = "Selected Interview Date",
                start = Convert.ToDateTime(id.StartTime).ToString("s"),
                end = Convert.ToDateTime(id.EndTime).ToString("s"),
                allDay = false,
                dismiss = false,
                className = "css-cal js-cal-obj js-cal-obj-" + id.Id
            });
        }

        var appArr = apps.ToArray();

        var jsonResult = Json(appArr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
```

So this is fine and the events render fine on the page.

What I am really struggling with is how to access the event id on the calendar slot itself.

My Date click event is as below:

```
            dateClick: function (info) {
                $.post("/Job/SaveInterview", { jobId: jobId, date: info.dateStr, duration: interviewDuration })
                 .done(function (data) {
                     calendar.refetchEvents();
                 });
            }
```

What I need is to be able to click on the event and fire a request back to my controller with an id so I can delete.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it in the end, see how below...

```
            eventClick: function (info) {
                $.post("/Job/RemoveInterviewSlot", { slotId: Number(info.event.id) })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        calendar.refetchEvents();
                    });
            }
```